# Horizontally and vertically center the image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried several versions regarding the centering of image in div and I failed. Please help.
This is html code (bootstrap)`

```
              <div class="carousel-inner cont-slider proizvodSlider">

                <div class="item active">
                  <img class="img-responsive prodInfoImg" alt="" src="images/l02.jpg">
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>`
```

Css:
`.proizvodSlider {
    height: 380px;
}`

I just need a fixed height, other styles can add arbitrary.

Comment: ask more precisely what do you want ?

Comment: I want to center horizontally and vertically that image in div.